# how to make it run:Analyse.get("2010-01-1","2010-09-1").mean?

Tags: ruby

require 'rubygems'

require 'mysql'

class Analyse

```
def self.get(from,to)

open('/tmp/result','w') do |wfile|

dbh = Mysql.real_connect("localhost", "root", "******")

dbh.query("use stock;")

result=dbh.query("select symbol,date,open,high,low,close from `#{symbol}` where (date > from and date< to) order by date asc;")

compute=[]

result.each{|row| wfile.puts row.join(";")}

end
```

end

def self.mean

```
amean=[]

open('/tmp/result','r'){|rfile|

  line=rfile.readlines

  line.each{|item|

  amean<< item.chomp.split(";")[-1].to_f

  }}

  amean=amean.compact

  amean.inject(0){|s,n| s+n}/(amean.size.to_f)

end
```

end

end

Analyse.get("2010-01-1","2010-09-1")  can get  a table  (date from"2010-01-1" to"2010-09-1")，
then input Analyse.mean, to  get the mean of close from "2010-01-1"to "2010-09-1" ,
how can i make Analyse.get("2010-01-1","2010-09-1").mean  to run ?

Comment: Could you please format your code as code? (see markup help)

Answer (score 0):

Your code above cant run it like that. Analyse.get() should return an object that responds to the method mean().

Comment: a frind tell me how to solve it , add  object = Analyse.new  and  return  object  in my code,thinks . it's my first to use stckover ,i don't know to  format my code,i will learn how to do it .i still have question to ask ,but the question is more complicated than this ,i can't express ,i need people who know chinese to help me,would you mind to do that?my friend can't solve it,if you want to give me help,please send me  email myocean135@yahoo.cn,i will express my problem in chinese.